# Sqlite : ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when try to fetch array from database

Tags: android, arrays, database, sqlite, cursor

i have create a table in sqlite that giving me java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException here is code while returning the array value.

```
    Cursor res = database.rawQuery("select "+QsDatabaseHelper.getItemName()+" from " + QsDatabaseHelper.getItemTableName(), null);
    String[] array = new String[res.getCount()];
    int i = 0;
    while(res.moveToNext()){
        String itemName = res.getString(res.getColumnIndex( QsDatabaseHelper.getItemName()));
        array[i] = itemName;
        Log.d("VALUE ",itemName+"name"); //There i geting all values
        i++;
    }
    return array[i]; //error showing this line
```

In my fragment i am calling this function to fetching itemname in string []

```
           String[] ItemNameArray = new String[list_counts];
                    for (int i = 0; i < list_counts; i++) {
                        ItemNameArray[i] = listcatDb.itemname();
                    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just return array. Because i value is increased inside the while loop. so just return array then use array values in the main thread or  if you want to return string use i-1;

```
return array;
```

Comment: thankyou i didnt not notice that mistake and i got the correct response after updating the code

Answer (score 0):

The exception `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` is thrown when the index is either negative or greater than or equal to the size of the array.
In while loop the value of 'i' exceeds size of array..
so it should be like

```
return array[i-1];
```

instead of,

```
return array[i];
```